# Showing a list of database entries

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to show a list of the names of my database entries. These entries are of type `FileField()`.

I am trying to show them in my `html` but nothing appears.

**Models.py**

```
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    the_file = models.FileField()
```

**Views.py**

```
class Showing_File(ListView):
    model = UploadedFile
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'the_uploaded_files_list'
```

**index.html**

```
 {% for file in the_uploaded_files_list %}
<h1>  {{ file.the_file }} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you tried ```{{ file.the_file.name }}```

Comment: @EdwinCruz no error pops up, my `index.html` appears but there is no list for some reason. There are plenty of entries in the DB so i should see them when it loads but nothing appears. my html code above is also contained within the body so it should be visible. I have tried `.name` but no joy with it

Comment: Add this ```{% empty %} 
    <h1>No objects</h1>``` to your template at the end of the for loop but inside of it and see if it displayes the h1

Answer (score 1):

basically FileField is a file type soo you have to add .url in the end to show the file in template

```
<h1>  {{ file.the_file.url }} </h1>
```